# Почему onclick не работает?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Уже много времени ломаю голову над событием onclick. Подскажите, почему то что стоит в событии onclick (к примеру, просто console.log), выполняется СРАЗУ, без нажатия на элемент которому был присвоен этот onclick. А когда нажимаешь на элемент, то ничего не происходит (хотя, по идее должно).
 Что я делаю не так?
Как сделать так, чтобы то что в onclick выполнялось после того, как будет клик по элементу.
Вот пример:

```js
document.getElementById('f').onclick = console.log('work')
```

```html
 <button id="f">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Потому что эта строчка

```
... = console.log('work')
```

прямо здесь вызывает `console.log`, который ничего не возвращает.

```js
document.getElementById('f').onclick = function(e) { console.log('work'); };
```

```html
 <button id="f">Button</button>
```